# Extract data from ws1 to ws2 in excel with python

Tags: python, excel

I need a python script to extract data from an excel worksheet1 and paste it to worksheet2. Then delete worksheet1. However, the actual names of the worksheets are different. For example: 0000a, 0000b, 0000c, etc.

How do I compare the first four numbers of the names and if similar, combine them into one spreadsheet with the name 0000?

Thanks in advance for help. For an example see this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1h5_FO7MEwqMY8P5qVlTvKbtEiPk6mAUTJYtFVJ4g2jc/pubhtml to this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/1/d/1ZxkA9oQiHc-axoEzYIvVHwbQ5hlhjcHy5qrWoRiNVWc/pubhtml#

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the **xlutils.copy** method. I believe you are using the Python **XLRD** liberary for handling the sheets.

**xlutils.copy** : function in this module copies xlrd.Book objects into xlwt.Workbook objects so they can be manipulated.

You would use xlutils.copy to copy the xlrd.Book object into an xlwt.Workbook object:

```
from xlutils.copy import copy
wb = copy(rb)
```

You can find the documentation for a lot of other useful functions in your case here: http://pythonhosted.org/xlutils/index.html

Python xlrd : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd